# How to set default value for manifestPlaceholder

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, build.gradle

I'm using the manifestPlaceholder tag in the build.gradle file for a library project.

The person who uses the library should define it properly.

AndroidManifest.xml in Library:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="library_id"
        android:value="${libraryId}"/>
```

Build.gradle file on the application side:

```
        manifestPlaceholders = [libraryId: "example"]
```

Is there any option to override the manifestPlaceholder tag on the library side?

I just want to define a default value and user should be free to provide a value if he wants to change it.

Comment: Did you try to put `manifestPlaceholders` in `defaultConfig` at library's build.gradle? It works for me

Comment: Are you sure about it? I put a manifestHolder to the library's build.gradle, and the one which puts in the application side doesn't override the item.

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a [Manifest Merge](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html) strategy to get the desired effect?

On the app manifest you can add something like

```
<your-outer-element
    tools:node="replace">
        <meta-data 
            android:name="library_id"
            android:value="YOUR_APP_ID"/>
</your-outer-element>
```

And that will replace the `library_id` meta data found inside the `your-outer-element` found in the library Manifest

Comment: note that this does not work with android:name elements, thus not being possible to override a service class for instance